# Why are some of my videos I just uploaded to Youtube in HD and some aren't?

Tags: video, youtube, screen-casting, full-hd

I recorded two tutorial videos using Hypercam, and then edited them with Windows Live Movie Maker, both of which exported "For High Definition Display"(or something like that), but when I uploaded them to YouTube, for some reason, one of them has HD up to 1080p, but one of them has no HD and only goes up to 360p, why is that?

NOTE: The video file itself, the one I uploaded to youtube, is in HD, so why isn't in HD on YouTube?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Youtube took some extra time to process the HD. Both are showing in HD now.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Seemed like there was only 360p available. Tip: Try playing the video on a different YouTube account and see if HD shows up. Even though there was initially only 360p available on my upload account, there was HD available when I tried using another YouTube account.